# PullToRefreshStaggeredGridView recreate when one fragment close

Tags: android, android-fragments, pull-to-refresh

i created my app with `PullToRefreshStaggeredGridView`. Its working fine. My application is one activity has 2 fragment. 1st fragment is list of courses. 2nd fragment is feeds. I have implemeted `PullToRefreshStaggeredGridView` for feeds. if its 10 inch device 2 columns for feeds, if it is 7 inch 1 columns for feeds. Up to this ok working fine.

Problem is when user hide courses fragment,feed fragemnt didn't adjust/refresh/update the view.After hide course fragment, there will be more spaces, so want to update the view/design.

This is my activity-

```
public class CoursesActivity extends Activity{
View listFragment;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

    if(!ECollegeApplication.isApplicationRunning()){
        ECollegeApplication.relaunch(CoursesActivity.this);
    }
    getPearsonActionBar(R.layout.action_bar,true);
    setContentView(R.layout.courses_main);
    listFragment = findViewById(R.id.listFragment);
    getActionbarItems();

    //click - fragment show hide
    ImageView dashboardshowhide = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.dashboardshowhide);
    dashboardshowhide.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DiscussionFeedFragment feedFragment = new DiscussionFeedFragment();
            feedFragment.initialLoad();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            if(listFragment.getVisibility()== View.VISIBLE){
                listFragment.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }else{
                listFragment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
   }
```

Design xml-

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/actiondivider"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="6dp"
    android:background="@color/actionbar_divider" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/listFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        class="com.mobile.courses.CousesFragment"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true" >
    </fragment>


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        class="com.mobile.feed.DiscussionFeedFragment"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true" >

    </fragment>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have 2 fragments called DiscussionFragment, CoursesFragment.

I want to recreate/adjust the fragment panel , when user click show/hide button.

My design is-

[image: This is my design]

Comment: Is it a fragment or are you implementing sliding menu??

Comment: Its a fragment. one activity has 2 fragment

Comment: I think you need [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)